# How to Optimize the URL in R

Tags: r, function, url, optimization

can anybody help me through the URL optimization in R.

Actually I need to get multiple organization related CSV file from URL.
I have to just change the one parameter in url to get that particular organization CSV table.

So mainly I was writing a function to extract that.
Example:

> data<-function("bank"){table<-read.csv(url("***://.....=string.....")}

can you guide me on this.

Comment: Can you give an example of what your urls look like?

Comment: Please expand your answer, show what you've tried so far and provide a minimal reproducible example if necessary. As the questions currently stands, it's too broad to answer.

Comment: Function looks like: data<-function("bank"){table<-read.csv(url("https://.....=string.....)} so here I have to just change the string and i can get the data for a particular organization. I am able to do it individual basis. But planning to write a function to optimize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you are looking for?

```
Data <- function(string){
table <- read.csv(url(paste("https://.....=", string, "...", sep="")))
# ...
}

# then you can change the parameter with function call
# (also dynamically using apply or a loop )

Data(string="bank")
```

Comment: Thank you Christian .. It works after slight change.. :)